# Coldfusion at VScode localhost refused 8080

Tags: json, coldfusion, visual-studio-code, localhost, vscode-debugger

I wrote code with Visual Studio Code. When I try to debug my code, Chrome debug doesn't allow the to connection localhost. How to fix the debug settings with launch.json setting?

launch.json code

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        {
           "type": "chrome",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
           "url": "http://localhost:8080",
           "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

http://localhost-8080.com/ refused to connection with Chrome

[image: Screen Shot Error Message]

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` !== `http://localhost-8080.com` make sure you're using the first domain.

Comment: Have you confirmed that localhost is even running?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno where can ı look as ım using the first domain?Thanks

Comment: @JamesAMohler How ım confirmed?Thanks

Comment: @Kayhan The image shows that you're trying to connect to `http://localhost:8080` and getting no response. The reference to the `.com` is Google checking that you entered the correct URL. Do you have a local ColdFusion server installed and running on your computer? If it's installed, is it setup to use port `8080`? You can't view the result of your code without a CF server running to process it.

Answer (score -2):

But CF is adobe cold fusion and adobe has no work with this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31446351)